# Wireless Adapter Driver not available for Linux

Tags: drivers

After trying out Ubuntu in a Windows 10 virtual box I have now decided to switch over to Ubuntu as my main OS on my PC.

When I used Windows 10 I used a wireless adapter instead of the default WiFi card inside my PC as it was slow and had started to cause major issues.  When I get onto Ubuntu I cannot connect to any of the networks in my home because the driver for my WiFi adapter only appears to be available for Windows.

The WiFi adapter in question is the `A6210 - AC1200` High Gain WiFi USB Adapter — 802.11ac Dual Band USB 3.0. The website I am on to get the driver is [Netgear.com](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/A6210.aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic#Software%20Version%201.0.0.35%20(Supports%20Win10)).

I have my laptop with me so I can easily just download the driver onto a USB stick and get it onto my pc but I am just not sure how to get the compatible version.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c335 Logitech, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc.
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp.
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If anyone could spread some light on the situation I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be [a Linux driver for that](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210#netgear-a6210). Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
wget https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd Netgear-A6210-master
make
sudo make install
cd ../..
rm -rf temp/
```